# How can I get data from XML [2 identical children and I want only 1 of them]?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have got XML file. This is his structure:

```
<data>
 <pos1>
 </pos1>
 <pos2>
 </pos2>
 .
 .
 .
 <pos3>
   <pos1>
   </pos1>
 </pos3>
</data>
```

I want only first data from `<pos1>`. If I use `$xml->getElementsByTagName('pos1')` I received all data.

Is it better way than get all elements from data and then search pos1?

Comment: I can do this, but I have got hundreds of XML files and not always `<pos1>` is on first place.

Comment: Then how you choose between the two if it isn't by position? What's the criteria?

Comment: One of them is in `data`, other one is nested in `<pos3>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`DOMXPath::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) :

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($yourDomDocument);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//data/pos1');
```

Above xpath query only return `<pos1>` that is child of `<data>`.